# Training output drops to 0 after fixed timesteps and again retrains in LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have the task of predicting the temperature based on 4 inputs. In the data given, the temperature increases non linearly to a certain limit and then reduces. It looks similar to the following graph:
[Temperature trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDVlL.png)

In order to create the LSTM model, I appended 3 data files, scaled the data between 0 and 1 and reshaped the input and output data taking 200 timesteps into account. For input data,it looks as follows

```
num1=int(len(X)/1000)
X=X[:num1*200].reshape(-1,200,4) """X is input data array of 4 columns"""
```

Then I built an LSTM model with 3 layers (20 neurons in 1st, 10 in 2nd and 5 in third) + 1 dense output layer. With all the options and callbacks, it looks as follows:

```
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss',mode='min',verbose=1,restore_best_weights=True,patience=600)
def train_model(lrate=0.3e-4):
  model=Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(20,name='LSTM_20',input_shape=(None,4),activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
  model.add(LSTM(10,name='LSTM_10',activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
  model.add(LSTM(5,name='LSTM_5',activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
  model.add(Dense(1,activation='linear'))
  opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lrate)
  model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=opt)
  logdir="C:\\Thesis\\logs"
  logdir =logdir+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
  tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir,histogram_freq=1)
  model.fit(X,Y,epochs=15000,batch_size=64,callbacks=[early_stop,tensorboard_callback],\
            verbose=1,validation_split=0.1)
  return model
```

With the flexibility of changing the learning rate, I have tried to train the model as best as possible but the output always comes out as follows:
[Sample Output from model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEGWL.png)

On closer inspection, the sudden drop in the output occurs at every 200 timesteps that I have mentioned in the model creation :
[Magnified model output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2YeF.png)

I have tried changing the timesteps to other values but this always occurs and I am at a loss to explain this phenomenon. Anyone have ideas/solutions for this? Thanks

Comment: Hi, shouldn't you be setting `return_sequences` to False in your last lstm layer? Otherwise your output is 1x5 matrix and also were you able to relate the number 200 to any paramater in your architecture?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is using Stateful LSTM. It has worked for me.